# I can't run windows pods on windows_ltsc_containerd node on GKE Cluster: Container OS does not match host OS: Unknown

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I don't seem to be able to run any windows containers on a node from a node pool which uses the `windows_ltsc_containerd` host OS on a GKE Cluster.

According to the logs, I see:

```
Normal   Created    12s   kubelet Created container runner
Warning  Failed     7s    kubelet Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: hcs::CreateComputeSystem runner: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.: unknown
```

Now I've confirmed that the pod is being scheduled onto the Windows node pool, my Dockerfile is here (I've pared it right back to the bare essentials):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
WORKDIR /runner
```

The image runs fine when running in Windows locally, yet for some reason the host OS doesn't match the container OS, despite them both being windows LTSC. What am I doing wrong?

I presume it's something to do with the image type on the host OS on the node pool:
[image]

I couldn't pick any other type of windows image for the node pool though. My K8S version is: `1.27.8-gke.1067004`. The Windows build version inside the container is:
`20348.859.amd64fre.fe_release_svc_prod2.220707-1832`

Here's the output of the node in `kubectl get-nodes -o wide`

```
gke-f73265-hrf3                        Ready    <none>   47m     v1.27.8-gke.1067004   10.128.0.75     35.232.15.79      Windows Server 2019 Datacenter       10.0.17763.4974   containerd://1.6.19-gke.1
```

The pod is definitely being scheduled onto this node.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I should have been using `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` instead of `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022`. That resolves it.